# changing meta value and meta key of price field

Tags: custom-post-types, customization, woocommerce-offtopic, post-meta

I have theme that uses price field. its price is stored in "S1" meta key.
next is woocommerce that use simple _price meta key to tore price values.

i want that when user enter price in theme feild it get stores in _price instead of "S1"

I tried this code

```
<?php
add_filter('woocommerce_get_price','reigel_woocommerce_get_price',20,2);
function reigel_woocommerce_get_price($price,$post){
    if ($post->post->post_type === 'post')
        $price = get_post_meta($post->id, "price", true);
    return $price;
}
```

but it doesn't change any thing.

i change manually meta key S1 to_price in database its not working

please can you help me in this.
i am new to all this.
thanks